# API web-developer

Tags: python, php, ruby, c++, perl

Добрый день! Имеется такой вопросик к ЗНАЮЩИМ людям...вы наверное знаете, что такое биржа вирусного маркетинга (заработок с помощью соц/сетей - пример: sarafanka). К специалисту с какой специальностью необходимо обращаться если требуется создать нечто подобное? Вот обычный PHP'шник, скажем, здесь вряд ли сможет помочь, т.к. при создании такого проекта требуется интеграция с соц/сетями на уровне API соц/сетей.

Как называют веб-девелоперов, которые работают на уровне API соц/сетей?

P.S. Извините если что за такой глупый вопрос)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API потому и пользуется такой популярностью, что язык тут практически значения не имеет. Так что грамотный php-шник тут не намного хуже остальных. Нужно просто искать людей с опытом работы с API. Хотя я бы не сказал что там что-то сверхсложное, даже, скорее, на оборот…